# Чтение ролей цветов в режиме реального времени

Tags: pyqt5

Подскажите, есть ли готовая программа, которая показывает роли цветовых схем Qt в режиме реального времени?
Есть ли аналогичная для ролей Breeze KColorScheme?

Что-то типа этого:

Источник тут:
https://qtdocs.narod.ru/4.1.0/doc/html/qpalette.html
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]